# Android Firebase Real-Time Database Triggered Push Notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've created an app similar to Instagram, using Firebase as my back-end database. The app has all the features i.e users can like your post, comment on your post etc. But, now I am stuck with notifications part. I've read some docs about FCM and followed some tutorials. However, I couldn't find any specific tutorial on how to create notification with the title as the name of the person who liked/commented on the post, and body of message as the content of the comment. Do I have to use PHP and mySQL to do this all? Or it can be done solely using JAVA?

Comment: juat 5 clicks and little changes in codes are required to setup fcm. i suggest you to check the website again for step by step setup instructions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't have enough rep to comment so I'll put this here.

Firebase released [Firebase Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) recently.

> Functions integrates the Firebase platform by letting you write code that responds to events and invokes functionality exposed by other Firebase features.

Lucky for you, the problem of sending notifications when one of your users follows another user is one of the example use cases for Firebase Functions. 
You can check it out [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications).

Comment: Thanks TrueKojo! I've successfully implemented the follower push notification using cloud function. However, do you have any idea to generate different tokens for different users under one device?

Comment: I'll have to investigate. My first inclination would be to use the unique IDs of the users from the Firebase Authentication flow.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you'll need to make an app server to send notifications from device to another. Your app server will have the API of firebase FCM, and service account of Firebase database.

Following is a node.js code.The function listenForNotifications() is a listener attached to your database as to whenever you want to send lets say a follow request. On follow button click in your app you will add the an entry in your database in "Following" root node. Then as the entry is added from your mobile app the request.on("child_added"..) gets fired as there is an entry. Then the function routes the message to the person you want to send request to via the Token. i.e request.requestToToken

Database Structure of "Following" node:

```
+--Root
+-.
+--.
+----Following
+---------pushKey /auto-generated
+----------------requestToToken /token of device you want to send notification
+---------------- requestFromToken / token of device that sent the notification

    var firebase = require('firebase-admin');
    var request = require('request');
        const express = require('express');
        const app = express();

        app.get('/', (req, res) => {
          res.status(200).send('Hello, world!');
        });

        // Start the server
        const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
        app.listen(PORT, () => {
          console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
          console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit.');
        });

        var API_KEY = ".......your key"; // Your Firebase Cloud Messaging Server API  
        // Fetch the service account key JSON file contents
        var serviceAccount = require("....your database service account.json");
        // Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
        firebase.initializeApp({
          credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
          databaseURL: "https://dropit-b357a.firebaseio.com"
        });
        ref = firebase.database().ref();
        process.stdout.write("I AM HERE... SERVER RUNNING MAYBE: ");


        function listenForNotificationRequests() {

          var requests = ref.child('Following');
          requests.on('child_added', function(requestSnapshot) {
            var request = requestSnapshot.val();
            sendNotificationToUser(
              request.requestToToken, 
              request.requestFrom,
              function() {
                return;
              }
            );
          }, function(error) {
            console.error(error);
          });
        };

        function sendNotificationToUser(username, message, onSuccess) {
          request({
            url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type' :' application/json',
              'Authorization': 'key='+API_KEY
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              notification: {
                title: message
              },
              to : username
            })
          }, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) { console.error(error); }
            else if (response.statusCode >= 400) { 
              console.error('HTTP Error: '+response.statusCode+' '+response.statusMessage); 
            }
            else {
              onSuccess();
            }
          });
        }

        // start listening
        listenForNotificationRequests();
```

Comment: *firebaser here* We actually just released [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions), which could take the role of the app server. Have a look at this sample of that: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications.

Comment: Thanks Omair for your answer. However, I've chosen to use the cloud function to perform same action and it is easier!